# Django equivalent of Rails's x.days.from_now

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, django

Is there Python/Django equivalent of Ruby on Rails

```
 x.days.from_now
 x.years.from_now
 Time.now + 7.days ???
```

working with time and date seems a lot easier in Rails!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`datetime.datetime.now`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now) to get the current date and time and [`datetime.timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) to create a datetime object offset from the current time however you like. For example:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

now = datetime.now()
seven_days_from_now = now + timedelta(days=7)
print now, seven_days_from_now
```

Answer (score 3):

Try [`timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) or more specific to django, there are some helper functions (aka. template tags) that are useful at the template level when using dates:

**[`timesince`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#timesince)**

```
{{ obj.created_on|timesince }}
```

**[`timeuntil`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#timeuntil)**

```
{{ obj.starts_on|timeuntil }}
```

**[`naturaltime`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/humanize/#naturaltime)**:

```
{{ obj.created_on|naturaltime }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 15, 15, 43, 37, 968000)
>>> datetime.now() + timedelta(7) # days
datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 22, 15, 43, 47, 234000)
>>>
```

You can also use the `replace` method of a `datetime` instance to replace individual components.