# x.time.from_now Rails implementation in Python

Tags: python, oop, python-datetime

In Ruby on Rails if you can call datetime methods on integers that returns datetime objects.

For example, `1.month.from_now` will return a datetime object that is 1 month from now. Quite self explanatory.

I'm aware that Python has its own standard datetime library and even some libraries with magic such as [beautiful-date](https://pypi.org/project/beautiful-date/). Hence my question is not a repeat of [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296222/django-equivalent-of-railss-x-days-from-now). Where the answers explained how to get the resulting datetime object.

My goal is to add that method to integers in Python such that I can use the exact same syntax as Ruby on Rails.

What would I have to do to do this?

Reasons: Just for fun.

Comment: The way it's done in Ruby is by extending original "Numeric" class. So probably a good way to start is to play around with extending classes in Python (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526858/how-to-extend-a-class-in-python). Posting as a commend, because it's just a pointer where to start looking.